# Angular NgbDatepicker mobile issue

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, frontend

I have a weird issue in a project using NgbDatepicker.
After resizing the calendar to mobile view: I have one date selected, I click on another day and hold down the mouse.

Drag the mouse (pressed) to another day. Release the mouse
-> now I have two days selected (but in the HTML only the first date is "true" and only the styles somehow apply to the second date).

[image]

I think this has something to do with the https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api

I do not know how to debug this issue as it is part of the api, and no typescript functions with click or drag are available for that calendar.

Does someone know anything regarding this issue or how should I proceed?
ANy help wold be appreciated. This issue is on mobile only.

Comment: I think the issue with mouse drag. Can you add code to prevent mouse drag when you are choosing the date(on calendar open).

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue. One thing we can do use is when user clicks or select a date close the datepicker window using (datechange or (dateSelect)="onDateSelect($event)) events

Comment: you can use datepicker pop-up. Please go through this link once  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#popup

Comment: Thank you, I realised that they actually have this "bug" but the styling is in a different way so you don't notice it, and it my project the colors were the same as in active state.

Comment: is your problem solved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html is generated from the ng bootstrap library, so the actual problem was the styling that was done. Some sass added and the issues was fixed.